# Which species has the greatest population in the Federation?

Tags: star-trek, federation

The Federation by the 24th century is indeed a very large union. I was wondering though, if there was any indication of which species formed the largest portion of the Federation's population by the 24th century (I don't mean to ask if there's a species that occupies greater than 50% of the Federation, but rather which member of the Federation (in terms of species) has the greatest population).  I'm not asking for exact numbers either, as that would be particularly difficult I imagine, but rather if there is *any* reference to the species with the greatest population in *any* Trek materials.

Comment: From what we've seen on screen I'd have to say human! Although I do wonder if that's Starfleet rather than the Federation?

Comment: The Tkon certainly have the largest known population of any species ever encountered. I am unsure about Federation members though. We certainly see more humans than any other species, but this is possibly just because we are shown humans more often.

Comment: I would guess the Tribble? They seemed to procreate absurdly fast.

Comment: @Wolph: I almost said Tribbles, but they were driven extinct by the might Klingon Empire.

Comment: @JamesSheridan But then brought back by the Defiant crew onto DS9.  Quick!  Begin the great Tribble Hunt anew!

Comment: Most likely some species of virus or bacterium -- or did you mean to limit the question to sapient species?

Comment: @KeithThompson - He specically asks about the Federation's population. To the best of my knowledge, no virus or bacterium is a member (yet) in any of the canon or non-canon materials

Comment: @Richard - you would be correct in saying that.  Neither am I aware of any viruses or bacterium that have joined the Federation

Comment: Is "Descendants of James T. Kirk" an ethnic group in itself? Or, for that matter, "Descendants of Will Riker"? Because both are serious contenders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Geoffrey Mandel's "[Star Trek : Star Charts](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Star_Charts)" (which isn't generally considered truly canon but was at least 'advised on' by Senior Trek Designer Michael Okuda) indicates that the homeworld population of **Andoria** was 38.2 Billion, representing some 3.2% of the total population of the Federation of just under 1 trillion.

[image: Andoria Population]

Per this [excellent answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39287/roughly-how-many-humans-are-there-in-the-star-trek-universe) we can reasonably assert that the Human population (including Earth and its associated colonies) was anything between 12 and 20 Billion in the same time period, representing some 2% of the total population of the United Federation of Planets.

Purely as a matter of interest, the Borg planet of Arehaz (AKA Borg Prime) had a combined population of over **50 Trillion** in the same time period

[image]

Comment: Sweet child of Satan, 50 Trillion!? I take back what I said about the Tkon. What did they do, hollow the planet out and make it an apartment block?

Comment: @jamessheridan - and that's just one planet. Total population is over 100 trillion.

Comment: @Richard - when you say 'total population is over 100 trillion', are you referring to the *entire* Borg species, or just in that system?

Comment: @n.soong -  apparently that's the **entire** Borg population.

Comment: @Richard - quite surprising.  I would have thought that they wouldn't have such a substantial population concentrated in the one place.  Perhaps this suggests the Borg have more things to do than assimilate species (perhaps processing assimilated knowledge takes a lot of resources?)  Anyway this is sort of getting off topic

Comment: Assuming an Earth-sized surface area, this would correspond to a population density of about 100,000 drones per square kilometer. This is very dense, but today we do have individual city districts with a population density over 100,000/km^2 as shown in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_city_districts_by_population_density), though no real-life city has a total population density that high as shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_by_population_density).

Comment: Also, it's not like Borg cities would need living rooms or parks or bathrooms or whatever, so you could really pack 'em in like they were on a Borg cube.

Comment: Nitpicking: If the reference number is 'just under 1 trillion', 38.2 billion account for a percentage > 3.82%.