# How many ships did Starfleet have during Star Trek Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship, star-trek-enterprise

How many ships did Starfleet have during the 22nd century? I remember and an episode where the Klingons attacked near earth and three ships came to the enterprises aid, one was the intrepid, and there was the other NX 02 that appeared later on.

Comment: Related, if not dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9566/roughly-how-many-starships-are-in-starfleet

Comment: Just specifically enterprise time frame before the federation was formed

Comment: IIRC there were only three NX vessels in use by the end of the show's run (not counting the last episode).

Comment: What class of vessel were the other two that fought of the Klingon vessel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR - We know of between 11 and 26**

There's quite a few ships I've listed here, so I'm going to break it down into categories:

## Certain

These are starships we *know* were in Starfleet's service during the 22nd century

### In canon

- [*Columbia* NX-02](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Columbia)
- [*Enterprise* NX-01](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Enterprise_%28NX-01%29)
- [*Intrepid*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Intrepid)
- [NX-Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/NX-Alpha)
- [NX-Beta](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/NX-Beta)
- [NX-Delta](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/NX-Delta)
- [*Republic*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Republic)
- [*Sarajevo*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sarajevo)
- [*Saratoga*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Saratoga)
- [*Shenandoah*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shenandoah)
- [Warp Delta ship](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Earth_starships#.22Warp_Delta.22)

### Beyond Canon

- [*Challenger* - NX 03](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Challenger_%28NX-03%29)
- [*Discovery* - NX 04](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Discovery_%28NX-04%29)

## Uncertain

These ships may have been in Starfleet's service during the 22nd century, but we **don't know for sure**

### Canon

- [*Bonaventure* (C1-21)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bonaventure_%28C1-21%29) - described as an 'Early Earth Starship'; whether it was in Starfleet service at the time of *Enterprise* is unknown
- *[SS Buckaroo Banzai](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/SS_Buckaroo_Banzai)* - this was an Earth starship, but we don't know if it was in service under Stafleet or not
- [*SS Emmette*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/SS_Emmette) - again we know this was an Earth starship in the 22nd century, but don't know if it was a Starfleet vessel
- [*Enterprise* XCV 330](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28XCV_330%29) - we don't know when exactly this starship was in service or if it was a Starfleet vessel, but it could well have been
- [*SS Hokule'a*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/SS_Hokule'a) - this was serving during the 22nd century, but we don't know whether it was part of Starfleet
- [*HMS Lord Nelson*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/HMS_Lord_Nelson) - again, was operating in the 22nd century but we don't know whether it was in Starfleet Service
- [*HMS New Zealand*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/HMS_New_Zealand) - as above
- [*SS Seattle*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/SS_Seattle) - as above
- [*SS Tomobiki*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/SS_Tomobiki) - as above
- [*SS Urusei Yatsura*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/SS_Urusei_Yatsura) - as above
- [*VK Velikan*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/VK_Velikan) - as above
- [*VK Yuri Gagarin* - as above](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/VK_Yuri_Gagarin)

## Beyond Canon

- [*Bonaventure* (10281NCC)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bonaventure_%2810281NCC%29) (*TAS* isn't canon)

This leaves us with 11 ships we are certain of.  But there could be anywhere from 11 to 26 ships **that we know of**.  It is quite likely Starfleet had a number more; I'm not even considering alternate timelines and the Mirror Universe.  I expect that this is a gross underestimation of the number of ships Starfleet had during the 22nd century, but as I say **this is just what we know of**.